# How to stop threads of following type in Java used for watching folders for files using WatchService for folders by using jToggleButton

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I would like to stop threads generated in the following manner by using jToggleButton. The threads are used for watching folders for files. I tried a lot, and searched alot, but am not successful. Could any body help and suggest any solution to stop threads generated like. The threads are shown alive in Netbeans debugging even after pressing the jToggleButton.
I have tried the volatile condition for stopping, 
FYI: I have a jToggle button for starting and stopping the threads.

The code is generated by Netbeans, so there is some extra code, but you may only focus on the code inside the jToggleActionListener and the code in another class: Thanks for your help.

```
package threadnames;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level; 
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jToggleButton1.setText("Stop");
    jToggleButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(84, 84, 84)
            .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
            .addContainerGap(142, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(25, 25, 25)
            .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
            .addContainerGap(28, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    if (this.jToggleButton1.isSelected()) {
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            Path home = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            WatchService watcher;

            watcher = home.getFileSystem().newWatchService();

                home.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
            Runnable task = new FileWatch(watcher);
            exec.submit(task);
            boolean terminated;
            terminated = exec.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            if (terminated) {
                System.out.println("All tasks completed.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Some tasks are still running.");
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } else {
        exec.shutdownNow();
    }
}                                              

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info    javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;


            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException |        javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class
                .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
public javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Here is the other class for the run():

```
package threadnames;

import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.nio.file.Watchable;

final class FileWatch implements Runnable {

private final WatchService watcher;

FileWatch(WatchService watcher) {
    this.watcher = watcher;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        WatchKey key;
        try {
            key = watcher.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            break;
        }
        Watchable dir = key.watchable();
        System.out.println(dir);
        for (WatchEvent<?> evt : key.pollEvents()) {
            System.out.println("   " + evt.context());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why? Those threads just print the statement and then end. Why/when do you want to end them?

Comment: Most of the threads will have finished by the time you try to stop them.  Why are you trying to stop threads which will stop themselves?

Comment: I don't really understand - do you want to stop threads that are members of a particular class, do you want to disable starting threads by extending runnable and creating a new Thread object, what exactly do you want to 'stop'?

Comment: The thread should automatically stopped after printing on console.

Comment: simply use `Thread#interrupt()` instead of manual stop flags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168430/countdownlatch-interruptedexception/3168465#3168465

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, thanks all for your informative answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I kill a thread? without using stop();](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915156/how-can-i-kill-a-thread-without-using-stop)

Comment: @zapl kindly check now my question!

Comment: @NathanHughes, kindly check now my problem and suggest a solution if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use thread interruption status

Use the interruption state of the thread to terminate a loop. This is better than a flag you create yourself because it makes your task usable with an `ExecutorService`; you can cancel a specific task through the `Future` you received when it is submitted, or you can interrupt all tasks with `shutdownNow()`.

Unless your task is running in a thread you create and manage yourself, it's safest to re-assert the interruption status after detecting interruption, so that your caller can deal with it too. In other words, all threads and tasks need to have a defined interruption policy and to be used accordingly.

### Example

Here's an example `Runnable` task using [`WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html):

```
final class FileWatch implements Runnable {
  private final WatchService watcher;
  FileWatch(WatchService watcher) { this.watcher = watcher; }
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
      WatchKey key;
      try {
        key = watcher.take();
      }
      catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        break;
      }
      Watchable dir = key.watchable();
      System.out.println(dir);
      for (WatchEvent<?> evt : key.pollEvents()) {
        System.out.println("   " + evt.context());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's how you could use such a service:

```
public static void main(String... argv)
  throws Exception
{
  Path home = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"));
  WatchService watcher = home.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
  home.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW);
  Runnable task = new FileWatch(watcher);
  ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
  exec.submit(task);
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  exec.shutdownNow();
  boolean terminated = exec.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  if (terminated)
    System.out.println("All tasks completed.");
  else
    System.out.println("Some tasks are still running.");
}
```

Because the `FileWatch` task correctly supports interruption, you will see that this test shows all tasks are completed soon after `shutdownNow()` is called. If you add tasks that use some other termination method to the `ExecutorService`, you will see that they continue to run.

### The code in question

There are a couple of problems with the code as it stands currently. Here's analysis of the `jToggleButton1ActionPerformed()` event handler, which is invoked by the Swing Event Dispatch Thread (the *EDT*) when the button is pressed.

```
When the button is pressed,
  create a new ExecutorService as a local variable.
  If toggle selected,
    submit a file watching task to the executor, and
    block the EDT for 1 second, or until the executor is shutdown.
  Otherwise,
    shutdown the newly-created executor.
  Discard reference to the executor.
```

The first problem is that since the executor service is never stored anywhere but a local variable, once that method exits, a reference to that particular instance is lost forever, and there's no way to invoke `shutdownNow()` on it.

The second problem is that, if really want block the EDT (probably not a good idea) until the executor terminates, you should do it after invoking `shutdownNow()` (in your "else" clause, when toggle is unselected), not after submitting the task. Look at my example above again and you'll see that I await termination only after I shutdown the executor.

Hoist the ExecutorService variable out of the method, and make it a member variable of your class. This will allow the toggle button handler to access *the same instance* of the `ExecutorService` and shut it down. Then, move the wait for termination to the unselected toggle branch.

This is what the flow should be:

```
When the button is pressed,
  If toggle selected,
    create a new executor service and assign it to a member variable, and
    submit a file watching task to the service.
  Otherwise,
    shutdown the executor, and
    wait for the service to terminate.
```

Also, for your use here, a `newSingleThreadedExecutor()` would suffice.

Comment: Thanks @erickson for your help. I implemented your solution in my application, but it does not work there, where as i tried itself, it does work. LET me explain, First, in my application, the treads (for watching 5 folders) are created after pressing a jToggleButton like: By calling Runnable task = new FileWatch(watcherSeperateForEachFolder), and I implemented the exec.shutdown in the jToggleButten when it is pressed back. Still the threads do not kill despite calling exec.shutdown();

Comment: Also,In my application, the WatchService when knows there is a new file in the watched folder, it generates another thread for processing that file! It means there are child threads as well, but the finish when the run() of the child thread ends.

Comment: I tried your code with a jToggleButton, your code also does not work. I mean still the threads are running, the executor is not shutdowned! Please give me a suggestion! your cooperation is highly appreciated!

Comment: @AhmadullahAchakzai Are you using `shutdown()`, or `shutdownNow()`? Only `shutdownNow()` cancels running tasks. You shouldn't need a thread per location, but one thread per watcher, and each watcher should serve one whole file system. Your button should just register the path with the existing `WatchService`, which is being polled by the other thread.

Comment: Thanks, i have used shutdownNow() in your above suggested code with jToggleButton. I used ur code. I tried to paste the code here, but that is a bit lengthy than the allowed characters here. can you tell me how to send you the code since i am new in this forum!

Comment: @AhmadullahAchakzai The very best thing you can do is edit your question to [include the *very simplest* working example (SSCCE)](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem you are having. It may not be much like your real application, but that's okay, as long as the fundamentals are there to allow others to run your code and see the problem.

Comment: I have created the SSCCE GUI with Netbeans which has some extra code as Netbeans generates usually, and used your code for watching a directory. Should I post that instead of my original question?

Comment: I have modified my post!

Comment: thanks for your detailed reply @erickson.I am sure it will help much. I will follow your directions, I hope this time I am successful. One thing more, I would like to create 5 threads by using a for loop inside the jToggleButton selection, submit them to the executor, will shuttingDown the executor kill all of the threads or I will have to kill the threads one by one using their reference?

Comment: Do you mean you'll create an `ExecutorService` with a limit of 5 threads? Or do you mean that you'll submit 5 tasks to one executor? Or are you creating `Thread` instances in addition to the `ExecutorService`? If you use one executor service, all its threads will be stopped by `shutdownNow()` when its running tasks complete, which will be right away if they're interruptible. If you create your own `Thread`, it's up to you. If you just want to watch multiple locations, you only need one `FileWatch` task; register its `WatchService` with multiple paths. Then a single-threaded executor is fine.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use a `stop` method that sets a `volatile boolean` to `true`.

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {
  private volatile boolean stop = false;

  public void run() {
    if (!stop) {
      System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }
  }

  public void stop() {
    stop = true;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      HelloRunnable hr = new HelloRunnable();
      new Thread(hr).start();
      hr.stop();
    }
  }
}
```

If the thread might be blocked you can arrange to interrupt it but of course this is not guaranteed to interrupt the thread as it may not be blocked, just busy.

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {
  private volatile boolean stop = false;
  private volatile Thread thread = null;

  public void run() {
    thread = Thread.currentThread();
    if (!stop) {
      System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }
  }

  public void stop() {
    stop = true;
    if ( thread != null ) {
      thread.interrupt();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      HelloRunnable hr = new HelloRunnable();
      new Thread(hr).start();
      hr.stop();
    }
  }
}
```

This last technique should also work if using [WatchService.poll(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html#poll%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) or [WatchService.take()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html#take%28%29).

It should also interrupt the thread if it is busy with most IO processes.

Comment: @SteveBenett - No more than OP does.

Comment: The problem with this is approach is that `ExecutorService` only uses thread interruption to stop running tasks. Rather than creating a non-standard API to set a new flag, it's better to make your task check for interruption. Of course, there are some blocking operations your task might need to do that were poorly designed, failing to support interruption or a timeout. There's not much help for that.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, kindly check now the question and suggestion any solution.

Comment: @AhmadullahAchakzai - This solution should still work in your case. Record the thread when run begins and interrupt **that** thread when you want it to stop.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Thread.stop()` method, but is has been [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html), because it's unsafe.

Instead of using the deprecated method(s), you can modify some variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running.

Comment: Or, in the example provided, you could just wait a few microseconds... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use some `flag` inside the `run` method to check whether to exit the method or not, by this way you can indirectly exit the `run` method.
Stopping a thread by any other method is currently not advisable.
See [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)