# How to stop threads used for watching folders by using WatchService?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I would like to stop threads generated in the following manner. The threads are used for watching folders for files. I tried a lot, and searched a lot, but am not successful.

Could any body help and suggest any solution to stop threads generated like the following:

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
         WatchService for files in folders which starts and runs here
         while (someCondition) {
               create a thread for copying some file which exits when run() finishes 
               created in another class which implements Runnable class
         }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
       for(int i = 0;i< 5; i ++)
        new Thread(new HelloRunnable()).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you want to stop it?

Comment: Are you actually using [`WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18722259/823393

Comment: Yes, I am using WatchService in a thread, so I generate 5 threads using the same WatchService while each one has its own folder for watching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `boolean someCondition` variable which is shared between the running thread and thread that wants to stop it.  This variable needs to be `volatile` however to make sure that it's value is updated between the threads.

Another idea is to test the thread interrupt flag:

```
// thread that is spinning doing some job like watching a file
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
   ...
}
```

Then you can call interrupt from another thread to stop it from running:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(...);
thread.start();
...
// tell the thread running in the background to stop
thread.interrupt();
```

Like always, you need to be careful about catching `InterruptedException`.  Something like the following is always a good idea:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    // re-interrupt the thread now that we've caught InterruptedException
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    // probably quit the thread
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gray for your reply, but I have 5 threads generated. if I call thread.interrupt(); will it kill all the 5 threads?

Comment: No, `thread.interrupt()` interrupts that particular thread.  If you want to kill all threads then you should keep all 5 `Thread` instances in an array or collection and then interrupt them all @AhmadullahAchakzai.

Comment: I used while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !someVolatileBooleanCondition),    It stops watching the folders, but the threads are not killed!

Comment: For the thread to die, it must exit its `run()` method @AhmadullahAchakzai.  Take a look at its stack trace to see where the thread in question is hung up.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stop a thread - its run() method must complete and exit. So check your condition in the run() method to ensure it eventually completes and exits.