InterruptedException causing application restart after running virtual threads for a few days
I'm encountering an issue with my application, which uses zulu-openjdk:21. To manage threads more efficiently, I encapsulated a method to wait for multiple threads to complete:
public static void joinThreads(Thread... threadList) {
    try {
        for (Thread thread : threadList) {
            if (thread == null) {
                continue;
            }
            thread.join();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("Virtual thread task exception", e);
        throw new BizException(CodeEnum.INTERNAL_BUSINESS_FAIL, "Virtual thread task was interrupted");
    }
}

The problem arises after the application runs for approximately five days, leading to the following exception and causing the application to crash and restart automatically:
ERROR com.xmonecode.tccompass.common.utils.VirtualThreadUtil - Virtual thread task exception java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1100)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:230)
    at java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.joinNanos(VirtualThread.java:824)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:2061)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:2154)
    at com.xmonecode.tccompass.common.utils.VirtualThreadUtil.joinThreads(VirtualThreadUtil.java:40)
    at com.xmonecode.tccompass.common.utils.VirtualThreadUtil.joinStartVirtualThread(VirtualThreadUtil.java:70)
    at com.xmonecode.tccompass.interceptor.RebateInterceptor.preHandle(RebateInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)

I have identified that the virtual thread gets interrupted while waiting. However, I'm unsure why these threads are being interrupted.
Additional Information:
JDK Version: zulu-openjdk:21
Framework: Spring Boot
Exception Location: Occurs during CountDownLatch.await() and VirtualThread.joinNanos() calls
Environment: Running in a containerized setup, with automatic restart on crash

After restarting, the application can run normally for a period of time.
Has anyone faced a similar issue, or can someone provide guidance on how to resolve this problem?
Thank you in advance!

The usual cause for an InterruptedException is that your thread has been interrupted. How are we supposed to know what is interrupting your thread? The amount of possible code is infinite.

Maybe some help from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168430/countdownlatch-interruptedexception

There is an RFE to add JFR events for interruption tracking: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8290332

@Holger, my guess is the only cause of InterruptedException  is that the thread has been interrupted :) . Loveshy, you should look for a classes which can have an access to this thread; off the top of my head I could think of ExecutorService.shutdown, most of its implementors will interrupt the threads they pool. StructuredTaskScope is unlikely your case. If that gives no results, then you might need to instrument java.lang.Thread and log interrupt method.
